# Auto Serial no in my lost and found sheet

Tags: python

I have a sheet in which serial format is like this 24/08/2017 basically serial no is 24 , is it possible to get next serial no which is 25/08/2017 by using formula

Comment: you mean next date?

Comment: Actually the fornat is set like this lets say I have 100 item then serial no will be 100/08/2017

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, if the serial number is irrespective of date,
you can do the following,

with s as the serial number,
and `/` differentiates the number to increment and the rest of the serial number, you can use string replace!

```
>>> s
'100/08/2017'
>>> s.replace(s.split('/')[0],str(int(s.split('/')[0])+1),1)
'101/08/2017'
```

If the serial number is in date format, you can use datetime module of python,

```
>>> from datetime import datetime,timedelta
>>> #serial_no = datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
>>> serial_no = "16/08/2017"
>>> print serial_no
16/08/2017
>>> print (datetime.strptime(serial_no, "%d/%m/%Y").date()+timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
17/08/2017
```

Comment: How do I execute this in excel Can you tell the formula

Comment: @RajeshThrithany, in _Excel_?! You didn't mention Excel anywhere in your question, and you tagged it with [tag:python]. Please edit your question and explain what you're trying to do in greater detail. That includes using proper tags. Please read [ask] for tips on asking effective questions.